# How To Enable Wireless Monitoring Macbook Pro

Tags: airport

I own a MacBook Pro Retina 15-inch, early 2013, and I would like to put the wireless card on board into monitor mode, but was unable to.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi zizon65, thanks for posting your question. Unfortunately it's really not clear. What does _put the wireless card on board into monitor_ mean?  Also, can you expand your question to include what you've already tried (saying _but was unable to_) does not help us to help you.

Comment: @Monomeeth I'm not sure what's unclear about this. Maybe it is just missing `mode` after `into monitor`?

Comment: **People voting to close** - This question is quite clear and very much on topic.  *Monitor* (mode) is to put it into a mode to "sniff" packets

Comment: Yes, that (adding _mode_) makes it clearer (for me at least). I think it was the combination of the _on board_ with the _into monitor_ that confused me. Thanks @Allan for the clarification.

Answer (score 6):

#### Use Terminal

You can use the `airport` utility.

It's located in a very obscure place, so I suggest creating a symbolic link to it:

```
ln -s /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport /usr/local/bin/airport
```

Now, you can put the WiFi (Airport) adapter into monitor mode:

```
sudo airport en1 sniff 6
```

This will sniff all packets on adapter en1 channel 6.  It will save a `.cap` file in `/tmp/airportsniffXXXXXXXXX`

You can view the output through [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or issue the command `tcpdump -r [filename]`.  For example, the following is the capture of my wireless adapter in monitor mode for a few seconds...

```
 18.0 24.0 36.0 54.0 Mbit] CH: 1, PRIVACY
17:37:37.746644 35635598us tsft 1.0 Mb/s 2412 MHz 11g -82dB signal -82dB noise antenna 0 Probe Response (yoyo) [1.0* 2.0* 5.5* 11.0* 18.0 24.0 36.0 54.0 Mbit] CH: 1, PRIVACY
17:37:37.774068 35662623us tsft bad-fcs 1.0 Mb/s 2412 MHz 11g -82dB signal -82dB noise antenna 0 Probe Response (LORRAINE) [1.0* 2.0* 5.5* 11.0* 18.0 24.0* 36.0 54.0 Mbit] CH: 1, PRIVACY
17:37:37.782831 35671401us tsft bad-fcs 1.0 Mb/s 2412 MHz 11g -84dB signal -82dB noise antenna 0 Probe Response (LORRAINE) [1.0* 2.0* 5.5* 11.0* 18.0 24.0* 36.0 54.0 Mbit] CH: 1, PRIVACY
17:37:37.793357 35683064us tsft 1.0 Mb/s 2412 MHz 11g -63dB signal -82dB noise antenna 0 Beacon (Go Noles ) [1.0* 2.0* 5.5* 11.0* 18.0 24.0 36.0 54.0 Mbit] ESS CH: 1, PRIVACY
17:37:37.796149 35686928us tsft wep 1.0 Mb/s 2412 MHz 11g -62dB signal -82dB noise antenna 0 Data IV:4767c7 Pad 20 KeyID 1
17:37:37.816820 35706464us tsft 1.0 Mb/s 2412 MHz 11g -79dB signal -82dB noise antenna 0 Beacon (yoyo) [1.0* 2.0* 5.5* 11.0* 18.0 24.0 36.0 54.0 Mbit] ESS CH: 1, PRIVACY
17:37:37.898203 35787820us tsft 1.0 Mb/s 2412 MHz 11g -62dB signal -82dB noise antenna 0 Beacon (Go Noles ) [1.0* 2.0* 5.5* 11.0* 18.0 24.0 36.0 54.0 Mbit] ESS CH: 1, PRIVACY
17:37:37.919172 35808864us tsft 1.0 Mb/s 2412 MHz 11g -81dB signal -82dB noise antenna 0 Beacon (yoyo) [1.0* 2.0* 5.5* 11.0* 18.0 24.0 36.0 54.0 Mbit] ESS CH: 1, PRIVACY
```

---

#### Use a GUI

1. Launch Wireless Diagnostics.  Press <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> and start typing "Wireless Diag...".  Press <kbd>Return</kbd> when Spotlight finds it.
2. Press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>7</kbd> (Window >> Monitor) to monitor the traffic on your Airport Adapter.

[image]

3. Press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>6</kbd> (Windows >> Sniff) to put the Airport card into "Sniff" mode.  Select your channel and start sniffing...

[image]

It will then start sniffing the network packets...When it's done, it will put a `.wcap` file on your desktop.  You can then use the file with Wireshark or with the `tcpdump` command.

[image]

Comment: Followed your answer, I tried to put my WiFi (Airport) adapter into monitor mode by issuing this command in terminal: sudo airport en1 sniff 6 but I got something different. How could I upload the wifi log file for to let you know what has happened?

Comment: You could try pastebin

Comment: I've uploaded the wifi log file to: http://pastebin.com/EC83DCXr

Comment: are you there Allan? Just wondering if you saw my last message saying that my log file has been uploaded to Pastebin.

Comment: What you have in pastebin is the standard error message from `airport`.  Two things you can try:  leave the interface off - `sudo airport sniff 1` and/or get the actual interface of your wireless adapter - `system_profiler SPAirPortDataType | grep Interfaces -A10`

Comment: ok I'll do so and will let you know later, because I'm on the road right now! Thanks.

Comment: Does it work with M1 processors?

Comment: I haven't tested as of yet (only have my iPad with me this week) @DarkSkull, but I don't see why it won't.  The utility should be the same, just compile for Apple silicon.